# Error "Unimplemented type : 7" for provide font files only on iOS devices

Tags: ios

there.
I have got a problem when using mapbox-gl-js.
I make a API to provide my own font files.
It work well on windows PC or android device.

When on iOS device (iphone, mac). it didn't work and I get an error like this:
`Error {message: "Unimplemented type: 7"}`

Here's what I do and searched.
I found this issue and make some help.
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/830

As the issue say, this error is for pbfs not being gizp compressed or not be served with `Cotent-Encoding: gzip`.
I checked my font files are being gziped well. (like ***.pbf.gz)
And here is the header of the response on Safari of mac. As you can see it has `Cotent-Encoding: gzip` with it.

```
Preview
URL: https://***/glyphs/65280-65535.pbf.gz
status: 200
source: network
initiator: ajax.js:147

request headers
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:path: ***/glyphs//65280-65535.pbf.gz
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15
Accept: */*
Host: ***
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: null
response 
:status: 200
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=“65280-65535.pbf.gz”
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Cache-Control: max-age=172800
Content-Length: 48529
ETag: ***
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?
If so, but why it' OK on windows and android. I'm really suffering from this error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake of my response headers, which is

> Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=“65280-65535.pbf.gz”

I delete it and have a try on iOS, it worked.
So I will close this question. Hope it helps someone. Thank you.